# connectedness can be checked on special fibre

Tags: algebraic-geometry, connectedness, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme over $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, $R$ a DVR with residue field $k = R/\mathfrak{m}$. I read an argument that said that if the special fibre $X_k$ is connected then $X$ is connected. Is this true without any assumptions on $X$? In the case I care about $X \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is affine (in fact finite) flat. Is the argument correct when we include one or both of these assumptions, and why?

Edit: As Mohan has pointed out in the comments, this cannot be true in the general case where $X$ is affine and flat. I'm curious whether it's true when $X$ is also finite. For example, I'm told $X = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(x^p-1))$ is connected but I don't see why. It's special fibre is clearly connected.

Comment: In the particular case where the map is affine can't you conclude that $X$ is affine? Let $X=Spec(S)$. What we want to show is that if $S\otimes_R k$ has no idempotents $\neq 0,1$, then $S$ has no idempotents $\neq 0,1$ either. Equivalently, that any idempotent $e\neq 0,1\in S$ gives rise to an idempotent $e'\neq 0,1\in S\otimes_R k$.

Comment: Flatness is not enough. Let $K$ be the fraction field of $R$ and let $X$ be the disjoint union of two copies of $\mathrm{Spec}\,K$, with the obvious map.

Comment: @user347489 Yes that looks like a correct translation to algebra. I'm just not sure how to show what you mention.

Comment: @Mohan perhaps I'm making a mistake or am confused about what the obvious map is here but if $X = \mathrm{Spec}(K \times K)$ then although flat and affine over $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ - and obviously disconnected - I don't see why the special fibre is connected.

Comment: The special fiber is empty. If you feel uncomfortable with connectedness of empty sets, this can easily be rectified, by taking $X=\mathrm{Spec}(R\times K)$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! Both good examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we have the following (apply it to the case $S = \operatorname{Spec} R$ where $R$ is a local ring and $X$ is a proper $S$-scheme):

**Claim**: Let $S$ be a topological space containing a point $s \in S$ which is contained in all nonempty closed subsets of $S$. Let $X$ be a topological space admitting a closed continuous map $f : X \to S$. If $f^{-1}(s)$ is connected, then $X$ is connected.

*Proof*: For any $x \in X$, the closure of $x$ in $X$ contains a point of $f^{-1}(s)$ (i.e. $\overline{\{x\}} \cap f^{-1}(s) \ne \emptyset$) since $f(\overline{\{x\}})$ is a nonempty closed subset of $S$ (hence contains $s$). Let $U_{1},U_{2}$ be two disjoint open subsets of $X$ such that $X = U_{1} \cup U_{2}$. Since $f^{-1}(s)$ is connected, then $f^{-1}(s)$ is contained in (exactly) one of $U_{1},U_{2}$; say $f^{-1}(s) \subseteq U_{1}$; if $U_{2}$ is nonempty, say $x \in U_{2}$, then $\overline{\{x\}} \subseteq U_{2}$ since $U_{2} = X \setminus U_{1}$ is closed, but this contradicts $\overline{\{x\}} \cap f^{-1}(s) \ne \emptyset$.

---

**Remark**: The ring $A = \mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]/(x^{p}-1)$ is in fact local: since $A$ is finite over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, all maximal ideals lie over $p\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, so the maximal ideals of $A$ correspond to prime ideals of $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_{p}} \mathbb{F}_{p} \simeq \mathbb{F}_{p}[x]/((x-1)^{p})$, which has a unique prime.

Comment: +1 If you have a proper map and a reasonable base (Henselian local) then the induced map on connected components of the whole scheme and the special fiber is a bijection. Funny enough, I don't see an easy way to extend your argument to prove that (the proof I know is [perhaps unnecessarily] hard)--do you see a way?

Comment: Hey, I don't know :/ Do you mean the argument in SGA 4.5, Exp. 1, Proposition 4.2.1?

Comment: Huh. Actually I didn't know a literature reference. It was an exercise in Illusie's notes on algebraic geometry, but it looks like essentially the same proof I had in mind (and was suggested by the section that the exercise was in).

Comment: Funny enough, I was reading Illusie's section on Grothendieck's existence theorem in formal geometry from the FGA explained book yesterday, for a mostly unrelated reason, and came across the exact claim you stated! It is Corollary 8.2.18 on p.195. The proof seems pretty simple and somewhat similar to the above one, except that you need to use Zariski's connectedness theorem and Stein factorization, which are not so simple.